# Cypress 12+ - Log in once for whole test run

Tags: cypress

My goal is to log in just once for the whole test run. To accomplish this, I did the following:

```js
// commands.js
const commands = {
  login(data = {}) {
    let { username, password } = data;
    username = username || 'example@email.com';
    password = password || 'testtest';

    cy.session(
      username,
      () => {
        cy.visit('/');
        cy.contains('Sign In').trigger('mouseover');
        cy.contains('Sign in with NBA ID').click();

        cy.get('[data-testid=email]').type('example@email.com');
        cy.get('[data-testid=password]').type('testtest');

        cy.get('[data-testid=submit]').click();
      },
      {
        cacheAcrossSpecs: true,
      },
    );
  },
};
```

```js
// e2e.js
// Session created
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.login();
});
```

```js
// user-profile.cy.js
describe('User profile', () => {
   // Session is restored here 
   beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit('/');
   });

  it('Open user profile', () => {
    // Here the site is open but not logged in.
    cy.get('#nav-controls').trigger('mouseover');

    cy.contains('My NBA ID', {
      timeout: 10000,
    }).click();
  });

  it('Check profile data', () => {
    cy.contains('First Name').next().should('have.text', 'Test');
    cy.contains('Last Name').next().should('have.text', 'Test');
    cy.contains('Birthdate').next().should('have.text', '10/1994');
    cy.contains('Country').next().should('have.text', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina');
  });
});
```

But when the first `it` comes, the page is open but logged out.

How can I log in just once for the whole test run?

Cypress version: `12.9.0`

Comment: follow this https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-data-session

Comment: Do you have any info about the way credentials are stored by this app? That would be necessary to debug what's going on, since there's no obvious mistakes in the implementation.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue until I added `{ testIsolation: false }` to my describe block.

```js
describe('User profile', { testIsolation: false }, ( ) => {
 it( )....

})
```